# use -a ,-p on read command togother

Tags: bash, scripts

In bash script can we read few array variables from the same line

How can I use `-a` & `-p` at the same time on read command?

I have tried:

```
read -ap 'vi:' var_1
read -pa 'vi:' var_1
read -a -p 'v1:' var_1
read -p -a 'v1:' var_1
```

None of which are working. Are they any other options?

Comment: what would you like to do? what is the expected input, and expected output?

Comment: What output is it giving you? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can append input strings to an array with a loop.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

array=()
while true; do
    read -rp "vi: " input
    [[ -z $input ]] && break || array+=("$input")
done

echo "${array[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method works in `bash` with a small modification:

Clear the variable

```
$ unset asdf
```

Put the option `-a` after the option `-p 'string'`

```
$ read -p 'enter 4 items separated by space ' -a asdf
enter 4 items separated by space  1 2 3 4
```

Check the result

```
$ echo ${asdf[@]}
1 2 3 4
$ echo ${asdf[3]}
4
$ echo ${asdf[0]}
1
```